# Why is the webservice returning null's?

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, .net-3.5, asmx

I have the following web-service:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="WebService" %>

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public Class Person
        Public FirstName As String
        Public LastName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal m_FirstName As String, ByVal m_LastName As String)
        End Sub
    End Class

    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetPersons() As List(Of Person)
        Dim lst As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)

        lst.Add(New Person("firstname_1", "surname_1"))
        lst.Add(New Person("firstname_2", "surname_2"))

        Return lst
    End Function
End Class
```

But it is returning:

```
{"d":[{"FirstName":null,"LastName":null},{"FirstName":null,"LastName":null}]}
```

It should be returning:

```
{"d":[{"FirstName":"firstname_1","LastName":"surname_1"},{"FirstName":"firstname_2","LastName":"surname_2"}]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assing FirstName and LastName in the constructor, so their values will stay null.
Add the following to your constructor:

```
FirstName = m_FirstName
LastName = m_LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

My VB is a little rusty, but I don't see the FirstName and LastName properties in your Person class.  I only see variables.  (Along with the missing assignment that was previously mentioned)